# Button is being covered by tabbar

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have a save button that is supposed to be located right above the tab bar and right under the table view, but it does not appear in the view when I switch to a smaller screen. There is auto layout on all the elements, and the button is centered horizontally, equal width to the view, and has vertical spacing between the table view and bottom. Any ideas on how to make sure the save button always appears in the position stated above? Auto layout was done through storyboard not code.

Comment: Can you upload a photo? A visual example would be helpful for understanding your question.

Comment: Also, if you could include the constraints you currently have, we can probably spot the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set height of `UIButton`, and do not set height of `UITableView`.